# Is there a way to allow cross account access to S3 files created using `aws_s3.query_export_to_s3` from RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I am exporting some data from Aurora RDS using `aws_s3.query_export_to_s3`, and recently had a need to access this exported data from a different AWS account. I noticed that files created by this export are encrypted with the default `aws/s3` KMS key. As far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be a way to export directly from RDS to S3 without a key or a customer managed key, and there is no way to give the other account permission to use the AWS managed KMS key.

Does anyone know of any way to achieve what I am trying to do, or am I out of luck?

Comment: I believe you can use a customer-managed key to do the export, it's mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-export-snapshot.html#aurora-export-snapshot.Overview

Comment: That is for exporting a snapshot, but I am just trying to export the results of a query.

Comment: I'm also meeting this issue today. In my scenario the database is in AWS accountA and the application is in AWS AccountB. when 'aws_s3.query_export_to_s3' is run, the rds encrypted the data using the 'aws/s3'  key from AccountB. So users from accountA is not able to get the data.

Comment: Hey @ipetrik, Did u try to disable the encryption?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great solution but here's what I did to solve the same issue:

Create your own AWS KMS key, grant the permissions for the other accounts to use that key and set it as the default for the bucket. Then write from RDS to the bucket. The data will now still have the wrong aws-amanged aws/s3 key. But you can change the key. Ther are two ways I know of:

You can select the files you wrote to S3 in the web-UI, click "Actions" -> "Edit server-side encryption" and choose "Use bucket settings for default encryption". AWS will then re-encrypt the files with the key that the other accounts can use.

Instead of manually changing the key in the web UI you can also just overwrite the files with themselves with `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/dir/ s3://bucket/dir/ --recursive`. The `aws s3 cp` uses the buckets default key.

Comment: Yeah, this is practically what we settled on.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly push/pull RDS (account A) to S3 (account B) with proper IAM role/permission (should have S3 bucket list,get,put access) at source RDS and destination S3 (1. S3 encryption KMS policy should have the source role added, 2. S3 permission policy should have the source role added) should also have the permission.